# Enumerate over time zones on a Windows Mobile device

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, timezone, dst

Is there a way to get a list of time zones available on a Windows Mobile 6 (or even better 6.5.3) device? I need information about the bias, the standard bias, the daylight bias and the shifting dates (as in [TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Those are the things I already tried:

- The registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Timezones` defines some time zones in binary format (`_REG_TZI_FORMAT`). It seems that Windows stores only time zone updates there, so the list isn't complete.
- The Windows API doesn't seem to provide a function to enumerate over all time zones.
- I maybe could map the time zones on Windows Mobile to the ones in Windows 7, but there are a lot of differences and this seems to be an error-prone task to me (besides of the hughe effort).
- The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458853.aspx) tells me that there's a `Timezones.csv` which ships with the Windows Mobile SDK, but I can't find it on my computer (neither in the 6.5 SDK folder nor in the 6.5.3 SDK folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenNETCF Windows CE](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/40acf5ae-3429-b8b0-82c9-30c38bc0fab7.htm) library allows to list the time zones available on a Windows Mobile device. Sample code:

```
var col = new TimeZoneCollection();
col.Initialize();

foreach (var timeZone in col)
{
  string name = timeZone.DisplayName;
  // ...
}
```

Internally, the library p/invokes the citydb.dll to obtain the information.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/wiki/Welcome) library, a port of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

It provides extensive information about time(zones).

Comment: Thank you for this hint. For some legacy reason I needed the list of Windows Mobile (which is sufficient for my use case, even if it hasn't been updated since 2009). In a new project I would use such a library as you suggested.